# positioning span on top of href and preserving click

Tags: css

My css skills are getting rusty, and I cannot figure out how to deal with this problem.

I've simple span that contains text "More" I need to place it on top of a href and preserve href capacity.

I tried to position it absolute but it still breaks click-ability.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the **span** within the **a** tag and call it a day. Otherwise, what you're looking to do is use the `z-index` property.

By setting a positioning property to the **a** tag (`position:relative` perhaps), you can effectively set and use `z-index: 2` to force the link to *sit above* the **span**. It might help to set `z-index: 1` to the **span** as well.

Comment: Hi, yes simplest would be placing it in a tag, but this is not possible, since link is spitted out by php function, I'd have to dig too much to modify this.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze Then try the alternative that I mentioned?

Comment: position relative on link fixed it :) ty.